# Multitenented Parallel Processing

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, parallel-processing, threadpool

I have a tomcat server with a handful of fairly long-running operations that I feel could be greatly sped up if broken up and processed in parallel.  What is the best practice as far as this is concerned?

I am concerned that if I just create some threadpool that is shared by all users, performance will be unpredictable and tank when the server has many users performing these operations (as they will all be competing for threads from the pool).  Is the solution just to create a really large pool?

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threadpooling is a tempting solution, but as you suspect its scalability can be limited in a real multi-user scenario.

In reality you're going to be limited by the number of cpus anyway and most of the time you're going to have more users than cpus so my experience is that attempting to parallelize a problem running on a webserver is futile unless you have a crazy number of cpus.